# Decryption: Using a loop to go through a function using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to make some code that displays a user's passwords for transfer to a new website. 
I have this right now.

```
function decryptPassword($users)
{
    global $sql_tbl;
    $userData=func_query_first("select * from $sql_tbl[customers] where login='".$users."'");
    if ($userData["password"]!="") $password = text_decrypt($userData["password"]);
    else return false;
    return $password;    
}

echo "master = ".decryptPassword('master')."<br>";

$a = decryptPassword('tester');
if ($a===false) {    echo "User not found...";exit();}
echo "tester = ".decryptPassword('tester')."<br>";
?>
```

and it works, but I wanted to use a for each query and I have been having trouble trying to get it into a a loop. Should I be doing this differently?

```
function decryptPassword($users)
{
    global $sql_tbl;
    $userData=func_query_first("select * from $sql_tbl[customers] where login='".$users."'");
    if ($userData["password"]!="") $password = text_decrypt($userData["password"]);
    else return false;
    return $password;    
}

$email=msql_query("SELECT email
FROM $sql_tbl[address_book] 
join xcart_customers on xcart_prod.xcart_address_book.userid=xcart_prod.xcart_customers.id
 where (default_s = 'Y' and default_b='Y'and membershipid=2) or (default_s='N' and default_b='Y' and membershipid=2)");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email)) {
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo " = ".decryptPassword($field)."<br>";
        $a = decryptPassword($field);
        if ($a===false) {    echo "User not found...";exit();}
        echo "it@claramente.com = ".decryptPassword($field)."<br>";
    } 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What database driver for PHP are you using? It doesn't look like you're doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and probably have a whole bunch of dangerous [injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure to be honest, I'm using a framework that my employer uses to establish the connection to the database.  I'm not sure how to escape this, and it's not going to be used more than once or have anyone input anything. Once it's done it's deleted.

Comment: If `mysql_query` is showing up, it's usually a sign someone's bypassing the framework.